# Can you open the doors of the Koppa Mining Site?

Tags: subnautica-below-zero

I'm exploring the Koppa Mining Site in Subnautica: Below Zero, and there are two giant closed doors in the first large room. There appear to be fish and resources beyond those doors, as well as fully modeled out equipment/items behind another:

[image]

[image]

Are these places ever accessible to the player?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, these doors can't be opened. You will have to find one of the two alternative routes to get into that room.

Take note that there is another set of doors within this room that cannot be opened. However, as of the latest update, there is nothing behind them and they exist as part of the design.